# Как генерировать псевдослучайные числа?

Tags: алгоритм, шифрование, случайные-числа

Ищу алгоритм, чтобы отталкиваясь от ключа, получать уникальную бесконечную (?) последовательность чисел в заданном диапазоне, с равномерным распределением.

В общем-то, любой `RAND(seed)` — то, что надо, только должен зависеть исключительно от seed'а, и воспроизводиться 1:1 на разных машинах.

Ну и ещё, далёкий прицел на шифрование, поэтому желательно, чтобы отдельные значения из последовательности не выдавали ключ и всю последовательность совсем уж очевидным образом : ) Поэтому, например, инкремент и остаток от деления не годятся.

Например. С "ключем" (или seed'ом) 0.123 генерится одна последовательность чисел, с ключем 0.456 — другая. На любом компьютере, в любое время из одного ключа получается одна и та же бесконечная последовательность. И, главное, генерируемые числа "ложатся" в промежуток от 0 до 1 так, что график распределения — горизонтальная прямая. Не "колокол" Гаусса, не чаще попадают в середину, чем по краям, не расчёска дискретных повторяющихся значений. Равномерное распределение.

Наверняка, всё очень просто, кто-то сходу подскажет. Поиски привели в дебри.

Comment: Вы сперва пишете "равномерное распределение", а затем "белый шум", они, конечно, похожи, правда плотность вероятности белого шума не ограничена отрезком [a,b], что невероятно сложно смоделировать на детерминированной машине с конечной памятью.

Comment: @Dex, упомянутая ниже [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BC) как раз пишет про «по всему диапазону задействованных частот», разве это не [a,b]?

Comment: @sergiks, сложно предположить, что они имеют ввиду конкретно, но в последствии связывают эту фразу так же и с цветным шумом. Я больше имел ввиду, что чем больше отрезок [a,b], тем "лучше" белый шум. Идеальный белый шум, имеет одинаковую плотность вероятности на всех частотах (0, inf]. Там даже картинка есть, "спектр шума, который можно считать белым", но он таковым, естественно, не является.

Comment: А советы из главы 3 [TAOCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) пробовали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Берёте ваш сид (пусть это будет 8-байтное число)
Дополняете его нулями до получения буфера нужной длины и считаете какой-нибудь хеш (SHA)
Получаете определённое количество случайных байт
Потом увеличиваете сид на 1 и повторяете процедуру, получая следующую порцию случайных байт

белее не бывает

Comment: Минус в том, что у двух сидов возможно полное совпадение последовательностей, начиная с n-ого числа ряда.

Comment: @sergiks - Не вопрос!  По сиду (8-байтному числу) считаете его хеш, это будет 20-байтный счётчик, к которому будете прибавлять единицу )))

Answer (score 3):

В [Википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BC) смотрели? там прям формула есть.

```
x[i] = 2 * ((rand()/((double)RAND_MAX)) — 0.5)
```

Или она выдает плохое значение?  Тогда нужно просто взять генератор случайных чисел с правильный распределением и подставить в формулу.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это как раз то, что необходимо @sergiks, но я не очень уверен, что это попадает под его определение "белый шум", который честнее честного. Хотя, в качестве "равномерного распределения" его рассматривать можно.

Comment: Как реализовать этот `rand()`, чтобы на разных компах при общем сиде последовательности совпадали?

Comment: обычно, генераторы завязываются на различные параметры системы (например, мак адрес сетевой карты), что бы сделать последовательности более случайными. Вам просто нужно сделать их зависимыми только от sid'a.

Comment: @sergiks, это так же немного странно, вы просите "белый шум", который даже в идеальных условиях при одних и тех же входных параметрах всегда будет случаен и некоррелируем. В таком же случае, как нужен вам, вы отдаляетесь от понятия "белый шум".

Comment: Под белым шумом я подразумевал ровный спектр, или просто равномерное распределение. Убрал из вопроса понятие шума.

Answer (score 2):

[[@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks)](/users/7161/sergiks), ты вот как задашь вопрос... Я потом уснуть не могу :) То про шифрование изображений, теперь это вот...

Я уже набросал один вариант, но получилось хероватое распределение (расческа), хотя в последовательности все хорошо — разброс нормальный (битовые сдвиги с различными условиями). Потерял нормальный прототип, так бы показал графики.

Возникла идея эксплуатировать проблему во благо: «[проблему 196](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_196)». Пока что считается, что это бесконечная последовательность, при том достаточно простая. Буду думать, как этим можно воспользоваться.

---

[Ну вот, собственно, и первый тест](http://bars.koding.com/test/rand_seed.html) (без паники, скрипту нужно несколько секунд; у меня генерируется и рендерится шум за 2-3 секунды для диапазона [0,0xFFFF]).

Работает, как я и говорил на основе проблемы 196, но недолго: вскоре происходит переполнение и все-таки приходится прибегать к операции mod (именно это, по всей видимости дает так много коллизий — их ~50% для последовательности длиной в 0xFFFF чисел). Но в целом — работает.

Вот сердце (JS):

```
function rand_seed($seed)
    {
    var $res = 196;

    var $limit = $seed + (($res * ($seed % 0xFFFFFFFF)) % 0xFFFFFFF);
    $limit = ($limit * $seed) & 0xFFFFFF;

    $limit = $limit % 0xFFFF;

    var $i = 0;

    while ($i < $limit)
        {
        $res = $res + parseInt($res.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) + $i;
        $res = $res % 0xFFFFFFFF;

        $i++;
        }

    return Math.abs($res) % 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
```

[rand_seed.js](http://bars.koding.com/test/rand_seed/rand_seed.js)

Использование:

```
var noise = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 0xFF; i++)
    noise[i] = rand_seed(i);

console.log(noise);
```

`rand_seed` выдает число в диапазоне `[0,0xFFFFFFFF]` (раньше было `[0,0xFFFF]`, я сейчас поменял, проверил, вроде работает).

На самом деле `rand_seed` является классом, в нем я организовал кеш, чтоб не перебирать постоянно `while ($i < $limit)` от нуля.

Comment: : ) Рад, что тебе интересно. Этот разброс сейчас потребовался всё для того же визуального шифрования: для покрытия изображения областями локальных трансформаций — их требуется много, и они должны перекрыть всю площадь за какое-то большое, но обозримое число итераций, расположенных на вид, случайно.

196 — здорово, не знал. Пока не вижу применения такой последовательности: как её проецировать на ограниченный интервал, чтобы распределение было равномерным?

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тема](http://rsdn.ru/forum/alg/1913888.flat), в которой обсуждается похожий вопрос. Вкратце, предлагается использовать криптографически сильный блочный шифр в режиме счетчика. Это будет понадёжнее обычного рандома.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какими характеристиками он будет отличаться от варианта @KoVadim, за исключением времени обработки. Ведь в любом случае количество ключей шифрования ограничено, поэтому идеальной плотности вероятности с P=const не будет. Поэтому не вижу смысла усложнять.